# PHP Mailer does not send all the necessary headers?

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can I make PHP Mailer send all the necessary headers, i.e all the headers that hotmal, gmail and yahoo requires.

Does anyone have a PHP Mailer class that sends all these headers?

Comment: use some standard library to send smtp authenticated mail, instead of mail function; i.e. Zend_Mail or some pear mail library

Comment: If you can't use or don't understand how to use the sendmail program from linux, you can use a PEAR object to send mail.

Comment: Zend_Mail will send all necessary headers? or i'll need to set all them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to `PHPMailer`, then some of the "extra" headers you set yourself when you add recipients, subjects and the from address. You can also add other fields, like changing the encoding or ading a replyto field.

Most of the other headers will be added for you when you add a HTML body as well as a text body or add attachments. That's the point of this class: it does a lot of that work for you as the raw `mail()` call in PHP is extremely simplistic.